# Can I deploy assemblies in .NET 4.0 under a .NET 4.5 App Pool?

Tags: .net, iis

If I've built and tested an application using .NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2003, can I deploy the application to Windows Server 2012 under the 4.5 application pool? In theory, .NET 4.5 uses the 4.0 .NET CLR so there shouldn't be any changes .NET wise? Or are there small changes to the CLR during updates?

Comment: The warranty you are looking for here is only worth what you paid for it.  You can trivially figure this out for yourself, just try it.  Come back when it blows up and you have a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4.5 is a "highly-compatible" release with respect to .NET 4.0. This is what Microsoft says. They also document some breaking changes.

You never know for sure that an app tested on a previous .NET version still runs correctly on a future version. It will certainly run 99.9% correctly and any issues will be easy to fix. That said there are always small and subtle breaking changes.

For example an application that I work on broke because they changed the type of the object stored in the `InnerException` property when a `SqlException` is thrown due to a timeout. Breakage is often due to such subtle things.

Depending on your correctness requirements you have to retest, or not.